# Getting image file size transferred with socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

in a `Node.js` with `Socket.io` project, i get an image via `Socket.io` like this:

```
socket.on('newImage', function (data) {
  var desc = data.description;
  var image = data.img; //i want file size of this
}
```

in this code, `image` variable contains image binary data, i want to detect file size of that image. how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how the data is encoded you can retrieve the byte length by using the [byteLength method](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_bytelength_string_encoding):

```
var encoding = 'binary';
var data = new Buffer('hello world', encoding);

Buffer.byteLength(data, encoding); // 11
```